# Cartesian product of two normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be groups and $A' \lhd A$ and $B' \lhd B$. Then prove that $A'\times B' \lhd A \times B$.

My proof is:

Take $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Then $aA'=A'a$ and $bB'=B'b$. Then $aA' \times bB' = (a,b)(A' \times B')$ and $A'a \times B'b = (A' \times B')(a,b)$. We can write $aA'$ instead of $A'a$ and $bB'$ instead of $B'b$. Thus, $aA' \times bB' = A'a \times B'b \iff (a,b)(A' \times B')=(A' \times B')(a,b) $ Hence, $A'\times B' \lhd A \times B. $

Is there any mistake in my proof? Thanks :)

Comment: Seems correct. Can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is easier using conjugation:

Let $a' \in A', b' \in B'$, and let $(a,b)$ be any element of $A \times B$.

Then:

$(a,b)(a',b')(a,b)^{-1} = (a,b)(a',b')(a^{-1},b^{-1}) = (aa'a^{-1},bb'b^{-1})$.

Since $A' \lhd A$ and $B' \lhd B$, we have $aa'a^{-1} \in A'$, and $bb'b^{-1} \in B'$, thus:

$(a,b)(a',b')(a,b)^{-1} \in A'\times B'$, that is $A'\times B' \lhd A\times B$.

---

As an aside, in the direct product $A \times B$, the elements of $A$ and $B$ "don't interact", so proofs about the direct product often boil down to two separate proofs in $A$, and also $B$.